# Limited Samples

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I’m having a problem that I think should have a simple fix.

I want to render my scene at full global illumination with 4096 sample.

I set all the sample settings to do so. However, when I actually click to render, the samples are limited to 300 samples. (See image).

I feel like I must have clicked something to limit it, but I can’t find where.

Thank you[image: screenshot of settings]

Answer (score 1):

Under *Properties* editor ... *View Layer Properties* tab > **Override** > *Samples* is set to 300 ... probably :)

[image]